# C++ passing a derived class shared_ptr to a templated function

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, boost, shared-ptr

First something that should work, then something that doesn't. Why doesn't it is the question.

I declare two classes:

```
class Base { ... };
class Derived : public Base { ... };
```

I then have the following function elsewhere:

```
void foo(shared_ptr<Base> base);
```

The following code should work right?

```
share_ptr<Derived> derived;
foo(derived);
```

Now, forget the above, I declare three classes:

```
class Foo { ... };
template <typename TYPE> class Base { ... };
class Derived : public Base<Foo> { ... };
```

Elsewhere, I declare a templated function:

```
template <typename TYPE> void foo(shared_ptr<Base<TYPE> > base);
```

The following code does not work:

```
shared_ptr<Derived> derived;
foo(derived);
```

It says that there is no matching function foo(...) found which accepts `share_ptr<Derived>`

First, should the original example work? And second, what do you think could be the issue in the second example where I have a `shared_ptr` to a class that is derived from a specialized base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the compiler will go through a level of indirection in that way. Rather, you can explicitly instantiate foo with TYPE set to Foo. Eg, the following compiles via g++:

```
#include<boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class Foo {};
template <typename T> class Base {};
class Derived : public Base<Foo> {};

template<typename T>
int foo(boost::shared_ptr<Base<T> > base) {return 0;}

boost::shared_ptr<Derived> derived;
int t = foo<Foo>(derived);

int main() {return 0;}
```

Comment: That's very interesting. Just that addition of `<Foo>` to the call of the `foo` function makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a copy and paste error, but just to cover all the bases, you missed the 'd' in 'shared' for `share_ptr<Derived>`.