# C++ instantiation of function template with shared_ptrs

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, shared-ptr, instantiation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ passing a derived class shared_ptr to a templated function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385355/c-passing-a-derived-class-shared-ptr-to-a-templated-function)

The compiler has no problems with instantiation when we use pointers.

```
template <typename T> struct Base{
  virtual ~Base() {}
};

template <typename T> struct Der: public Base<T> {
};


template <class T>
void f(Base<T>* b) {}

int main() {
  Der<int> x;
  f(&x);
}
```

However if I change f to use shared_ptrs, the compiler cannot find a match.

```
template <class T>
void f(shared_ptr<Base<T> >b) {}

int main() {
  shared_ptr<Der<int> > x(new Der<int>);
  f(x);
}

Z.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
Z.cc:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘f(std::tr1::shared_ptr<Der<int> >&)’
```

Changing x to

```
shared_ptr<Base<int> > x(new Der<int>);
```

will also work. 
Why is there this difference in behavior?

Comment: Can someone tell me why adding Foo to the call foo<Foo> in the duplicate question's answer magically makes things work?

Answer (score 0):

`shared_ptr<Der<int>>` is not implicitly convertible to `shared_ptr<Base<int>>` whereas `Der<int>*` is implicitly convertible to `Base<int>*`. C++ doesn't automatically make types instantiated from a template convertible just because the template parameter types happen to be convertible, because that doesn't necessarily make sense and could be dangerous.

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#conversion